# Is there a function in PyMesh which computes Volume?

Tags: python-3.x, computational-geometry, pymesh

I am trying to calculate the volume of an intersection in pymesh. From the MWE on the PyMesh website https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mesh_boolean.html, given `intersection`, I would like to know how to calculate the volume?

I have tried accessing the list of attributes from https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html?highlight=volume#mesh-data-structure, however the only attributes I have available are:

```
(Pdb) intersection.attribute_names
['source', 'source_face']
```

Does PyMesh have the ability to calculate the volume of this intersection (or any generic mesh for that matter)?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `intersection.volume`, it works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).